# Временная папка

Tags: php, php.ini

Настройки php.ini:

```
open_basedir="/var/www/html/site.ru"
upload_tmp_dir="/var/www/html/site.ru/tmp"
```

Потом создаю новый временный файл, а он создается в `/tmp`, куда соответственно доступа нет.

```
$tmp = tmpfile();
var_dump(stream_get_meta_data($tmp));

   array(9) {
     ...
     ["uri"]=>
     string(14) "/tmp/phpE7hLsa"
   }
```

Подскажите, может нужно еще что-нибудь настроить?

UPD: Web-сервер apache2. Папка на сервере существует, и даже файлы с форм нормально принимаются. А вот если создавать временный файл через `tmpfile()`, то он создается в `/tmp`

Comment: А папка существует в каталоге сайта? Какой используете web-сервер? Перезагружали ли web-сервер?

Comment: @And дополнила вопрос

Comment: А вы вызовите `phpinfo()` и посмотрите, какой каталог стоит и поменялось-ли там, на ваш адрес до папки.

Comment: @And в `phpinfo()` все как надо показывается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, похоже, что функция `tmpfile()` использует системную временную папку, и значение `upload_tmp_dir` в php.ini никак не влияет на директорию созданного файла.

Решила проблему таким образом:

```
$tmpFileName = tempnam(ini_get('upload_tmp_dir'), 'php');
$tmpResource = fopen($tmpFileName, 'r+b');
// какие-то действия с файлом
fclose($tmpResource);
unlink($tmpFileName);
```

Comment: Вы можете использовать функцию `putenv` для определения системной директории временных файлов (где `TMPDIR=путь`) и потом проверить это с помощью функции `sys_get_temp_dir`.